# Python Telegram Bot Conversation Handler strange return behavior

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a similar code to:

```py
OPTIONS, ADD_INFO = range(2)
shop_conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('select', select)],
    states={
        OPTIONS: [CallbackQueryHandler(options)],
        ADD_INFO: [CallbackQueryHandler(add_info)]
    },
    fallbacks=[MessageHandler(filters.COMMAND, conv_error)] # Just sends a error message and stops the conversation
)
async def select(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                'Options', callback_data='1'),
        ],
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                'Cancel', callback_data='2'),
        ],
    ]
 # Then the bot sends a message and the reply_markup is this keyboard, nothing relevant is done after this
     return OPTIONS

async def options(update: Update, _context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    if query.data == '2':
        await query.edit_message_caption(caption='Canceled')
        return ConversationHandler.END
    else:
      keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                'Add 1', callback_data='1'),
        ],
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                'Add 2', callback_data='2'),
        ],
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                'Cancel', callback_data='3'),
        ],
    ]
    caption = f'Your information is {get_user_info(update.effective_chat.id)}' # This function is 
    # defined in another file, it gets the user info from my database and everything works in this 
    # function, the info is displayed correctly in the captions
    await query.edit_message_caption(caption=caption, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))
    return ADD_INFO


async def add_info(update: Update, _context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
     query = update.callback_query
     await query.answer()
     add_user_info(update.effective_chat.id) # Function that adds the info to the db, works fine.
     await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=f'Info {query.data} 
     added')
     return OPTIONS
```

When this code runs, the expected behavior is:

User enters 'select' function where he can cancel the operation or select 'options'. When 'options' is selected, the reply_markup changes and he can choose between add 1 or 2 to his info, the current user info is displayed in the message too.

After the user selects a info to add, the next function is called, where the DB gets updated.

**The expected behavior** is to let the user continue to add info, and the info being constantly updated in the message.

**What happpens** is that when the user clicks one of the options, the info is added to the database but it doesn't change in the message until the user clicks it again, causing it to be constantly late, for e.g:

The user has the info: '11' -> User adds '2':

In DB: '112', In message: '11'

User adds '1' -> In DB: '1121', In message '112'

How can I sync the both informations?

Comment: The problem is that you update the message text only in `options` and not in `add_info`

Comment: @CallMeStag Is there a way to acess the `keyboard` defined in `options` on `add_info`? How can I pass data from one to another beyond using the `callback_data`? Using `query.edit_message_captions` makes the inline markup disappear.

Comment: you can e.g. define the keyboard as a global variable. Please also have a loot at [this wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Storing-bot%2C-user-and-chat-related-data)